# How to set Wireshark to log ONLY DNS requests?

Tags: linux, networking, centos, wireshark

This works:

```
tethereal -i eth0 -w /root/mycapture.pcap
```

but it captures every packet. I only need to capture DNS requests. Is this possible? The server is Linux.

Other thing is: is it possible to have the file saved over a network to another computer? The server only has a small hard drive that's not big enough for the capture file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify a capture filter using **`-f "port 53"`**.

*Side note: It's `tshark` now, not `tethereal` anymore.*

---

To capture locally but store the data on a remote server, use `-` or `/dev/stdout` as the output file, and pipe the command to `ssh`:

```
tshark -i eth0 -f "port 53" -l -w - | ssh otherhost "cat > foo.pcap"

tcpdump -i eth0 -f "port 53" -l -w - | ssh otherhost "cat > foo.pcap"
```

You can also do the opposite – capture on a remote server but store data locally:

```
ssh otherhost "tshark -i eth0 -f "port 53" -l -w -" > foo.pcap

ssh otherhost "tcpdump -i eth0 -f "port 53" -l -w -" > foo.pcap
```

Note: **Always** specify a capture filter when storing data like this. If you don't, each packet will cause an infinite loop.

Comment: The man page for `tethereal` and the [Wireshark User Guide](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChCapCaptureFilterSection.html) mention filters that are applied by default when run via SSH. In the first case (storing to remote server), this won't apply, but in the second case?

Comment: Thanks, that is capturing dns now. However i'm confused about getting the file saved on my local computer. I am using ssh to get into a server i own from a windows 7 laptop. How do i get the file to be sent to my laptop from the server as it's being captured?

Comment: @DanielBeck: Thanks, didn't know that.

Comment: @thebigapplee: Use the second method ("capture on a remote server"). If using PuTTY, replace `ssh` with `plink`.

Comment: and i replace 'otherhost' with what, how will it find my computer?

Comment: @thebigapplee: Replace `otherhost` with your server's address.

Comment: so i run that comand on my laptop?